# Why only one NIC obtains an IP address?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, dhcp

I'm learning on how to set up a network properly, and I'm a bit stuck.

I've created two separate Ubuntu Server VMs in VirtualBox, then connected them through an internal network (`intnet0`). With CLI manager I've set up DHCP server, and it works fine, both are getting IP addresses correctly.

Now, when I add second interface to one of the machines (host only network), this Ubuntu obtains IP for only one card, and it's always the first one. In this example, I've added host-only adapter as first, then internal network adapter as second:

[image: NIC config]

I suspect it's some kind of Linux setting, but I have no idea which one; I've already set the second NIC up with:

```
sudo ip link set enp0s8 up
```

but it's still not getting an address.

On the other hand, `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty. Should I configure it, or configure my networking manager through `netplan`? A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the second NIC on the same subnet as the first? If so, what are you trying to achieve with that configuration? Take a look at the comprehensive answers to this question on SuperUser: [Using DHCP to get two different IP addresses for two NICs on one Machine](https://superuser.com/q/1056054/399707), they should be able to help.

Comment: It is best to [edit] and add the commnad output as text, rather than a screenshot, as it is not possible to search a screenshot